# Firefox td width doesn't change with the first row's td

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, resize, row

I got a table with 4 columns and **several** rows.
The problem is that in firefox, if I resize the **first TD** in the **first row** from **80px** to **120px**, the width of the **first** TDs in the **other rows won't change** with the TD in the first row (which means the width of the other TDs remains 80px unchanged).
(Everything is ok in IE.)

I remember that if the width is set on any TD, then the entire column would have that width.  But seems Firefox didn't follow this rule.

The CSS related to the table is given below:

```
.grid .body_table
{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: do you any specific css written for table, please provide.

Comment: More code, please. Post the entire code (or URL) of a minimal case where the issue can be seen. The description is much too vague. For example, how do “resize the first TD”, and how did you conclude that it would not affect other cells of the same column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very similar to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=735579 and should be fixed in Firefox 14, if so.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, give a class to first td for the row like `<td class="first">` and in the CSS please do `td.first { width:120px }`.

Comment: The width is to be changed dynamically by JScript, so cannot give width value by using css class to that TD.